# Wordpress Woocommerce delete header image from new order template only

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a header image defined in my woocommerce email options.  However, I don't want to show that header image in the 'new order' email, just in the others.  Anyone have an idea of how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, in the email tab of the settings on Woocommerce:

- Find the tab "Processing order"
- At the bottom of the page there is a heading "HTML template"
- Click the "Copy file to theme" button
- Once that has copied click on the "View Template" button, this will open the file in a little editor.
- Find `?> <?php do_action('woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading); ?>` in that file, then
- Find the email-header.php file and copy all the contents from `$bg       = get_option( 'woocommerce_email_background_color' );` down to the end of the file.
- Replace `?> <?php do_action('woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading); ?>` with the content from the email-header.php file.
- Find the following code: `<?php if ( $img = get_option( 'woocommerce_email_header_image' ) ) {
  echo '<p style="margin-top:0;"><img src="' . esc_url( $img ) . '"
  alt="' . get_bloginfo( 'name' ) . '" /></p>'; } ?>` and remove it.

The order receipt emails to customers should now not include the header image (you can do the same for other emails if you wanted to as well).

Answer (score 0):

Above methos is absolutely working fine.
We can also do it by another easy step.

First we have to open email-header.php file from 
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails

Go to the WooCommerce => Settings => Emails => New Order in Admin Panel
Copy Text from Email-Heading textbox.
For me it is “New customer order”.

Find belove code in "email-header.php" under  “template_header_image”

```
<?php
      if ( $img = get_option( 'woocommerce_email_header_image' ) ) {
        echo '<p style="margin-top:0;"><img src="' . esc_url( $img ) . '" alt="' . get_bloginfo( 'name' ) . '" /></p>';
        }
?>
```

Important Note:
Make sure in belove code “if condition - if( $email_heading != "New customer order")” comparison text is copy from Email-Heading textbox from woocommorce admin.

Replace above codefrom "email-header.php" by Belove code

```
<?php
     if( $email_heading != "New customer order"){
        if ( $img = get_option( 'woocommerce_email_header_image' ) ) {
            echo '<p style="margin-top:0;"><img src="' . esc_url( $img ) . '" alt="' . get_bloginfo( 'name' ) . '" /></p>';
        }
     }
```

?>

You can do the same for other emails if you want to as well just make sure all different email catergories Email-Heading distinct.